# Breadcrumbs list in ActiveAdmin shows wrong name when using friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, friendly-id

I have a model named `Company` that has `code`. The column is used for `friendly_id`.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :code, use: :slugged
end
```

`ActiveAdmin` doesn't recognize `friendly_id`, so that I had to override `find_resource` method like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
  controller do
    def find_resource
      scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

With this code I can edit the model attributes by ActiveAdmin, but breadcrumbs list in edit page shows wrong company's name. (That is using `id`, instead of `code`)

Where and how can I configure to use `ActiveAdmin` and `friendly_id` at the sametime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`breadcrumb` method is defined in [lib/active_admin/dsl.rb](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb)

```ruby
# Rewrite breadcrumb links.
# Block will be executed inside controller.
# Block must return an array if you want to rewrite breadcrumb links.
#
# Example:
#   ActiveAdmin.register Post do
#     breadcrumb do
#       [
#         link_to('my piece', '/my/link/to/piece')
#       ]
#     end
#   end
#
def breadcrumb(&block)
  config.breadcrumb = block
end
```

Since it is executed in the controller, you can use your custom `find_resource` method to configure it to your liking!

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the idea to @mark-merrit, using the code below you can dynamically customize breadcrumbs:

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Company do
  breadcrumb do
    links = [link_to('Admin', admin_root_path), link_to('Companies', admin_companies_path)]
    if %(show edit update).include?(params['action'])
      links << link_to(resource.name, admin_company_path)
    end
    links
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, I was not intend to ask a question. I post it as an answer because I thought that a implementation may helps someone who come here from google.

Answer (score 0):

Does prepending :code to `config.display_name` in `initializers/active_admin.rb` work for you?

Comment: Sadly `config.display_name_methods = [:code]`, shows wrong `code`.